# doctrine how to use the clause: IN within findOneBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working in a project in Symfony2 and i Have an Entity Called File and what i am trying to do is get one File from the database with some criteria but the most important criteria is that the file should not match with given array of Ids and without implementing a method in the file Repository

```
$Ids = (1,2,3,4,5);
$file = $repoFile->findOneBy(array(
      'id'=> $Ids,    // the Id should not match with the array $Ids
      'deleted' => NULL,
      'isMain' => 1
  ));
```

how can i tell doctrine that the file should not match with the array: $Ids
and i prefer to do it directly in my class without having to implement a method in the file Repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `createQueryBuilder` for `NOT IN()` clause

```
$result= $repoFile->createQueryBuilder('r')
    ->select('r')
    ->where('r.id NOT IN (:ids)' )
    ->setParameter( 'ids', $Ids, \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY )
    ->andWhere('r.deleted = :deleted')
    ->setParameter('deleted',NULL)
    ->andWhere('r.isMain= :isMain')
    ->setParameter('isMain',1)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: it can't be done directly in `findOneBy()` function ?

Comment: @user3648485 No it can't be done using `findOneBy,findBy,findAll`